# Cleaning Resque failed jobs in Ruby application

Tags: ruby, redis, resque, resque-retry

I have been using resque in my ruby app with resque-retry plugin. I happened to have a db issue which results into 1M failed jobs. Now these failed jobs are not coming into the fialover queue immediately but taking some sweet time like 10k jobs per hour. I tried cleaning them by deleting redis list **resque:failed** but they are still coming into failover. Is there anyway I can remove all of these failed jobs that are stuck somewhere in the redis as they are not showing up but very slow.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Deleting following entries from redis did the trick

- all keys that matches **resque:delayed:***
- all keys that matches **resque:timestamps***